# How do I change the Text Background Color of a cellEntry in Google Java Spreadsheet API?

Tags: java, google-api

I'm currently doing some operations on my spreadsheet through the Java Spreadsheet API but I can't find in the docs(https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#working_with_cell-based_feeds) how to set the Text Background Color

Code:

```
        Map<Long, Integer> categoryStatisticsMap = populateSheetWithCategoryStatistics(statsHolder);
        URL cellFeedUrl = worksheet.getCellFeedUrl();
        CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);
        for (Map.Entry<Long, Integer> entry : leadToCellMap.entrySet()) {
            CellEntry cellEntry= new CellEntry(entry.getValue(), currentColumn, ""+categoryStatisticsMap.get(entry.getKey()));
            //cellEntry.whereIsTheMethodForSettingTheColorAndOtherStuffLikeBorders
            cellFeed.insert(cellEntry);
         }
```

I guess you do not set it on the cellEntry... Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there nay update on this? I'm also looking for some solution.